# How can I view 4 programs windows 2x2?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm looking for a way/tool to re-size my screens faster.

Problem is:

I want the 4 programs that I'm running to be shown in a nice 2x2 view so that I don't have to re-size the windows manually.

Comment: What have you researched and tried?

Comment: Ironically, that feature used to be easier in XP (maybe Vista too). You used to be able to right-click the taskbar, and then tile-horizontally/vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No extra software needed. Open the Task Manager by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>. Go to the Applications tab. Then while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, click which windows you want, then choose Tile Vertically.

[image]

The results is the windows will be given equal display area on the desktop.

[image]

Comment: nice alternative, but too much work...I prefer drag a window to a corner

Comment: Yes, that is a nice feature. It's really a matter of preference and whether you are willing to pay for WindowSpace. Using the Task Manager is free.

Comment: Not available in Windows 8/8.1. Funny now that I think about it because it's coming back with 10 (via snap).

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 now supports some more “tiling” via Aero Snap. You already know the following shortcuts from earlier Windows versions (starting from 8 IIRC):

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> Make current window fill right half of screen (snap right)
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> Make current window fill left half of screen (snap left)

Alternatively, you can drag a window to the left or right border of a screen to achieve the same.

Windows 10 supports additional modes:

[image]

You can now drag a window to a screen corner to make it cover the respective quadrant of the screen.

This mode can also be achieved with keyboard shortcuts. It’s a two-step process. First, snap window left/right (see above), then press:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> Move window to the left/right upper quadrant
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> Move window to the left/right lower quadrant

If a window is not snapped on the left/right side of a screen, the shortcuts will behave like before and maximize or restore/minimize the window.

There are additional behaviors when you use the shortcuts again on a “corner-snapped” window. They are useful especially on multi-screen systems. Just try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Use WindowSpace. It offers you the possibility to resize any window to a 1/4 screen size with just the movement of the window to the proper corner. I use it everyday.

Look:
[image]

Here is the website: http://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace.html